# AngularJS ng-repeat print 0 if any object missed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arraylist

**One object missed in 2nd array. Using ng-repeat there I want to print 0. Please find the below code**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item}}
      <div>
        <h3>{{item[0].name}}</h3>
        <div>
          <article>
            {{item[0].tc}}
          </article>
          <article>
            {{item[1].tc}}
          </article>
          <article>
            {{item[2].tc}}
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[code in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nRBpx7cMRHoR99HQKUXy?p=preview)

Comment: you can use something like this `{{item[2] ? item[2].tc : "0"}}`

Comment: Just add an OR in expression `{{item[2].tc || 0}}`

Comment: thank you... working for me

Answer (score 0):

Print the object or zero instead

```
  <article>
    {{item[2].tc || 0}}
  </article>
```

Or

```
  <article>
    {{item[2].tc ? item[2].tc : 0}}
  </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at your arrays in the plunkr - it seems as if you have to iterate over the items array twice:

```
//array from the plunkr
    $scope.items = [
      [{name:"a",tc:100}, {name:"a",tc:101}, {name:"a",tc:102}],
      [{name:"d",tc:103}, {name:"d",tc:104}],
      [{name:"f",tc:105}, {name:"f",tc:106}, {name:"f",tc:107}]
    ]
```

Nested ng-repeats - one for each items.array and then for each object in that array. given that each object has the same name - its fine to get the first one for the h3 - but then using the nested ng-repeat will allow retrieval of the objects in the array - irrespective of the number of them.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
      <div>
        <h3>{{item[0].name}}</h3>
        <article ng-repeat="itemDetail in item">
          {{itemDetail.tc}}
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If, for example, `item[0]` is missed then `item[0].name` will cause an error `Can not read property name of undefined`. You need to set default values to your data or use `{{(item[0] || {}).name}}`

Comment: *"will cause an error"* ... not in view expressions it won't. Do you see such error in your console in demo? Empty object won't produce expected results either

Answer (score -1):

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item}}
      <div>
        <h3>{{item[0].name}}</h3>
        <div>
          <article>
            {{item[0].tc}}
          </article>
          <article>
            {{item[1].tc}}
          </article>
          <article>
            <span ng-hide="item[2].tc">0</span>
            {{item[2].tc}}
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```